# what happened to json_encode in 13.10 php?

Tags: php, 13.10

Just updated to saucy 13.10 and `json_encode` is missing from the bundled php.  `json` doesn't appear in the `phpinfo()` output and i'm getting this error in my app:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_encode()
```

Anyone else experiencing this or know the fix?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Install `php5-json`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

This [used to be provided by `php5-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5%20json&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) but that has changed in Saucy. No idea why and seems like a silly thing to do but it's very simple to fix.

After the installation, make sure to also restart the Apache2 server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: thank you.  I found this explanation...funny stuff: http://iteration99.com/2013/php-json-removed-from-php-5-5/

Comment: Oh god, it's *that*?! I've read about that nonsense ages ago but never dreamed anybody would feel that it was legally contrary to the PHP license. What a waste of time.

Comment: @AlexButum It's still on iteration99.com - it's just not available at the moment. I'd guess it's a static site (eg Jekyll) that hasn't been rebuilt properly.

Answer (score 5):

When you install this package, if you don't see php5-fpm restart post install, don't forget to do the following:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Dude, thank U very much - only because Your answer I can use php-json lib, even after restart/reload nginx didn`t load this lib via fpm. Thx a lot.