# How to install Drupal on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-installation, drupal

I installed `drupal7` using the [Community guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Drupal) from the Ubuntu repositories.

Everything went fine, but when I open `localhost/drupal/install.php`  all I get is a blank white page.

I also tried with `localhost/drupal6/install.php` and `localhost/drupal7/install.php` but both gives me 404.

Comment: Have you tried with the others one? http://localhost/drupal6/install.php or http://localhost/drupal7/install.php

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I uninstalled, then reinstalled using the manual method. Now I get a 404 not found.

Comment: re-edit: Yes, I tried that. I get a 404 with all but this: http://localhost/drupal/install.php which as I said, results in a blank white page

Comment: Check if PHP and Apache services are running (`sudo service NAME status`). What do you see on `localhost/drupal`? (or `localhost/drupal6`, `localhost/drupal7`) Also, check that the *source code* is also blank (secondary click -> *Wiew Page Source*)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently php5-json was removed from php5-common.

[what happened to json_encode in 13.10 php?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361424/what-happened-to-json-encode-in-13-10-php)

This seems to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```